# Bash kube context and git branch prompt?

Tags: bash, git, kubectl

Anyone put together a clever/minimal kube context and git branch prompt for bash shell?

I found this for kube context:

https://github.com/jonmosco/kube-ps1

and am currently using this for git branch :

```
parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}
export PS1="\u@\h \[\033[32m\]\w\[\033[33m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ "
```

But before spending rest of the day merging those I might be that someone made a better job at this already?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using the following, which gives me a nice prompt (in colors) with the following format

```
[{{WORKINGDIR}}] [{{GITBRANCH}}] [{{NAMESPACE}}@{{CLUSTER}}] $>
```

```
[~/projects/a] [master] [dev@myCluster] $>
```

**PS customatizations:**

```
parse_git_branch() {
  git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ [\1]/'
}

k8s_info() {
  kubectl config view --minify --output 'jsonpath={..namespace}@{.current-context}' 2> /dev/null
}

## Customizations
PS1="\[\e[1;92m\][\w]\[\e[33m\]\$(parse_git_branch) \[\e[01;33m\][\$(k8s_info)]\[\e[34m\] $>\[\e[96m\] "
```